# How to create a table view dyanamically in javafx?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

In my app i have some sets of command which is unknown in the beginning. These command usually send some data .
I want to push all  executing command to table view of javafx.Currently i could able to do that using a observable arraylist.Currently i am updating the arraylist whenever new command  is coming.but i want to display each command  in different table view.For that i want to create the table view dynamically a/c to the command

Exp- suppose  i have 3 commands command 1 command 2 command 3
than i should able to create table according to the command that is executing if command 1 comes then i should create table and display its data in that .If  command 2 comes than  the application should create 2nd table and so on.
Any help on this will be appreciated .Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

for creating dynamic tables in javafx...first you need to a Java file with setter and getter properties and main final where you access it.

below examples show how its work...

User.java

```
public class User
{
int id;
String name;
 public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id= id;
} 
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

now you can can use this class in your main file

Main.java

set variables

```
public  static TableView<User> table;
  private TableColumn<User, Integer> ColId;
  private TableColumn<User, String> ColName;
ObservationList objlst = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

now you have to set Columns property for add data into them.

```
colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,Integer>("id"));
colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CustomerDetailDO,String>("name"));
```

now you can make two functions for fill and clean table

```
public void FillTable()
{
User ab = new User();
objlist.add(ab.setId(1));
objlist.add(ab.setName("demo"));
table.setItems(objlist);
}
```

and for clean table

```
public void CleanTable()
{
objlist.clear();
table.setItems(objlist)
}
```

use of these functions you can make updates and delete data into table

I hope this will work for you..